# Github User Lookup

Tags: beginner, form, elm

I have made my first app in Elm, a lookup of Github users.

You type the name of the user into the search bar and the user's username and profile image - which has an anchor linked to their profile - appears below.

Here is my code:

```
module Main exposing (..)

import Html exposing (..)
import Html.App as App
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (onInput)


main =
    App.beginnerProgram { model = model, view = view, update = update }



-- MODEL


type alias Model =
    { username : String }


model : Model
model =
    { username = "" }



-- UPDATE


type Msg
    = Change String


update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Change newUsername ->
            { model | username = newUsername }



-- VIEW


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div
        [ style
            [ ( "display", "flex" )
            , ( "justify-content", "center" )
            , ( "align-items", "center" )
            , ( "flex-direction", "column" )
            ]
        ]
        [ input
            [ placeholder "Search for a Github username"
            , onInput Change
            , style
                [ ( "font-size", "30px" )
                , ( "padding", "10px" )
                , ( "width", "600px" )
                ]
            ]
            []
        , div []
            [ h5 [] [ text model.username ]
            ]
        , a [ href ("https://github.com/" ++ model.username) ]
            [ img
                [ src ("https://github.com/" ++ model.username ++ ".png")
                , style [ ( "max-width", "200px" ) ]
                ]
                []
            ]
        ]
```

Here is a demo of it in action: https://alanbuchanan.github.io/GithubUserLookup.html

I used `elm-format` to format the code, and based the architecture from [the documentation](http://guide.elm-lang.org/architecture/).

1. The code returned in the view is messy. How can I tidy my code so that the styles applied do not take up space inside the main `div` of the view, perhaps instead within a variable beforehand?
2. How else can I optimise this code?

Answer (score 3):

From the functional point of view what you're doing is a bit odd as you always create a link and try to load an image, even for non-existing users.

You should better query the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/) and change your model to something like:

```
type alias Model =
  { username : String -- this is the string typed in the input box
  , user : Maybe User -- this is the parsed result from the API call
  }
```

then, you can create a `viewUser : User -> Html Msg` function to show the username and the image. Note that your model has a `Maybe User` so you'll have to pattern match in `view` and either call `viewUser` (if you have something to show) or display some text explaining that the current query doesn't match with a valid GitHub user.

Note that invoking the API and getting a result is a bit more convoluted than it is in JavaScript. You need to do an [HTTP request](http://guide.elm-lang.org/architecture/effects/http.html) and create a [Json decoder](http://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/json.html).

Said that, let's go back to the code you wrote. I agree with the comments in the [other answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/140481/github-user-lookup/140495#140495) and I'd like to add a few things:

- comments like `-- MODEL` are not particularly useful. I'd get rid of them;
- `Change` is not really self-explanatory. What does it change? I'd rename it to `QueryChanged` or something similar.
- as I mentioned already, `view` could be split in smaller functions each one taking care of visualising/styling a single component.

In your question you asked about how to optimise your code. Are you looking for performance improvement? Why?

Answer (score 2):

I would split out the each of the style definitions into a function of their own. For instance:

```
-- VIEW
mainDivStyles : Html.Attribute Msg
mainDivStyles =
    style
        [ ( "display", "flex" )
        , ( "justify-content", "center" )
        , ( "align-items", "center" )
        , ( "flex-direction", "column" )
        ]

formInputStyles : Html.Attribute Msg
formInputStyles = 
    style
        [ ( "font-size", "30px" )
        , ( "padding", "10px" )
        , ( "width", "600px" )
        ]

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div
        [ mainDivStyles ]

        [ input
            [ placeholder "Search for a Github username"
            , onInput Change
            , formInputStyles
            ]
            []
```

This cleans up the vie code considerably and makes it easier to read.